# Autoload issue in PhpStorm and Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, phpstorm

I have created a Laravel project using PhpStorm but when I open index.php in the browser it shows some errors.

It opens `http://localhost:63342/METU/public/index.php` but it should be `http://localhost:63342/index.php`.

```
Warning: require(C:\Users\ilhan\PhpstormProjects\METU\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\ilhan\PhpstormProjects\METU\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\Users\ilhan\PhpstormProjects\METU\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\Users\ilhan\PhpstormProjects\METU\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
```

What is wrong with my project?

Comment: You are using PhpStorm's own built-in web server, which requires project name to be in URL as well as actual path to the script (hence the `/METU/public` part in URL). You better use proper web server (Apache/nginx/IIS/etc) or use PHP's web server if you need "better" URLs. Class autoloading should work regardless the URL used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error generally occurs when you haven't run `composer install` on a new laravel project.  The autoload file it references will be created when you run that command.

As for the URL issue, you want to make sure your `localhost` is mapped to the `/public` folder of your laravel project, not mapped to the root of it.

Comment: Now I have run `install` https://i.imgur.com/0VY22Se.png and https://i.imgur.com/NiSe1Yy.png but there is no change sadly.

Comment: It worked when I've created the project without using PhpStorm.